# doctrine dql array and object at same time

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, dql

I have two entities and I want to get a list of distinct elements and their count from the first entity, and the whole second entity as objects. I'm not sure if I can explain it, because of my bad english.

So, this is the function:

```
public function findMostPopular()
{
    return $this->getEntityManager()
        ->createQuery("
            SELECT 
                e,
                COUNT(p.event) c,
                IDENTITY(p.event) m
            FROM AppBundle:Predictions p
            LEFT JOIN p.event e
            WHERE p.status = 'pending'
            GROUP BY p.event
            ORDER BY c DESC , m ASC
        ")
        ->setMaxResults(5)
        ->getResult()
    ;
}
```

When I try to call it, I'm getting this error:

**[Semantical Error] line 0, col -1 near '
SELECT
': Error: Cannot select entity through identification variables without choosing at least one root entity alias.**

Is it even possible this way to get what I want?

**Edit:** Example data in the table:

```
737117017
737117017
737117017
737561075
737561075
737561075
738821787
738821787
738821787
738848055
739040139
```

I want count of each distinct value. These are the foreign keys to the table with events, so I want the corresponding object from events table.

```
! c !  m        !   event                                    !
--------------------------------------------------------------
! 3 ! 737117017 !  the object from events with id 737117017  !
! 3 ! 737561075 !  the object from events with id 737561075  !
! 3 ! 738821787 !  the object from events with id 738821787  !
! 1 ! 738848055 !  the object from events with id 738848055  !
! 1 ! 739040139 !  the object from events with id 739040139  !
--------------------------------------------------------------
```

**Edit 2**

I got it work by following way. I'm sure, it's not correct, but I don't know the right way.

```
SELECT
    p,
    e,
    COUNT(p.event) c,
    IDENTITY(p.event) m
FROM AppBundle:Predictions p
LEFT JOIN p.event e
WHERE p.status = 'pending'
GROUP BY p.event
ORDER BY c DESC , m ASC
```

Comment: Well, I have to explain a bit more.

I want results like:

`[object], count, eventId`

Comment: I'm not suer I understand what are you trying to obtain. Please, could you update you question to show us the expected result?

Comment: where is the function `findMostPopular` located?

Comment: `findMostPopular ` is located In PredictionsRepository.php

Comment: the error is throw in the [Query Parser](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/Parser.php#L825) but I am not sure how to fix it. Can you try debugging there. Maybe the order in the SELECT statement is relevant and you need to put the `e` object at the end of the list as you are in the Repository for the `p` Prediction object.

Comment: It's not working. :-(

Comment: I think you should select from event and then left join with  Predictions...

Comment: I updated the question with a workaround, which i'm not sure is the correct way to solve the problem.

Comment: I am not sure if this is what you are searching for, but take a look at ResultSetMappingBuilder: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34556195/get-an-unmapped-field-in-a-native-query-in-doctrine2

Comment: Thanks, but mine is DQL, not native sql.

Comment: @NTsvetkov have you tried my suggestion?

Comment: @Oscar Pérez: Sorry, I didn't. I'll try tomorrow and I'll post the results.

Comment: @OscarPérez It worked! Thank you! The sql itself:     `SELECT
        e,
        COUNT(p.event) c,
        IDENTITY(p.event) m
    FROM AppBundle:Events e
    LEFT JOIN e.userEvents p
    WHERE p.status = 'pending'
    GROUP BY p.event
    ORDER BY c DESC , m ASC`

Comment: @NTsvetkov I'm going to add an answer, please, accept it if it solved your problem.

Comment: Done. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the referred problem you must change the order of your entities in the query, so it should be something like:

```
public function findMostPopular()
{
  return $this->getEntityManager()
    ->createQuery("
        SELECT 
            e,
            COUNT(p.event) c,
            IDENTITY(p.event) m
        FROM AppBundle:Event e
        LEFT JOIN e.predictions p
        WHERE p.status = 'pending'
        GROUP BY p.event
        ORDER BY c DESC , m ASC
    ")
    ->setMaxResults(5)
    ->getResult()
  ;
}
```